# Microsoft Azure - no SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Microsoft refers to creating an instance of a SQL Data Warehouse on Azure (NB NOT SQL Database), but there is no instance there that I can see. Please see attached screenshot of the Azure Portal Marketplace after typing in "SQL Data Warehouse".

This is part of their Data Science Associate Certification (Step 1 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/understand-the-sql-dw-connector-with-azure-databricks/2-setup-the-environment) so would really appreciate if anyone can advise on how to get around / resolve this ??

NB if I try to create instead a SQL Database I come unstuck at step 4 in the above link as there is no option for "Select Performance level".

KR, Barry Walsh

[image]

Comment: It has now been rebranded `Synapse`

Comment: search for synapse instead

Answer (score 1):

SQL Data Warehouse is now renamed as "Azure Synapse Analytics."

Answer (score 1):

This is now *Dedicated SQL Pool(formerly SQL DW)*

Answer (score 0):

Please create Azure SQL Data Warehouse database using the following method.

1. Click Create a resource in the upper left-hand corner of the Azure portal.
2. Select Databases from the New page, and select SQL Data Warehouse under Featured on the New page.

[image]

3. Fill out the form.

[image]

4. Select an existing Server or click Create new to create and configure a new server for your new database.

When finished, make sure you create a firewall rule that adds your client IP so you can connect to your database.

Comment: thanks all, much appreciated. I would request Microsoft update their certification material as its misleading/out-of-date and additionally clarify upfront the total cost of provisioning apps to complete the certification

Comment: A lot of innovations is aiming the Cloud these days, so it is difficult to keep documentaction updated. In a matter of weeks an article gets obsolete.